# Sound duration in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, audio, duration

I noticed many players display audio track duration before loading the sound file, but I cannot figure out how that is done.
So how can I get the duration of an mp3 file in Flex without having to load the file in a `Sound` object ? Think about loading 1000+ files in an application that has to immediately display the duration for each track.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  It's more complicated than I thought.  [This open source project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/vbmp3header.aspx) knows how to do it.  Even if you don't want to download the code, there are 7+ references for where to find the information on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I'm a Java guy and have no idea of .Net; Also I'm not aware of how to use .Net code in Flex.

Comment: you cannot use .Net code in flex - run the .Net/java code at the server and store the results in an xml file. Load this xml file in to flex.

Answer (score -1):

If you read just the ID3 metadata there is a chance the time information is there.

Comment: I just scanned through my collection of 11,000 or so MP3 file:  less than a thousand have an ID3 tag, and those are only tracks I've labeled.

Comment: ID3 tagging is the generally accepted way of obtaining length.  The alternative it to open up the file and interrogate the individual frames.  iTunes provides tagging for purchases, if you generate your own mp3 then it is up to your implementation to set the meta data.